# How to create Settings page on Android?

Tags: android, settings

I am trying to add a page in "Settings" menu option on top of the android app. The app by default had the 3 dots on top right corner and when I click on it, it doesn't go anywhere and now I am trying to implement settings to my app. What I have done so far is following,

Created xml file in /res/xml folder called preferences.xml with following content;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preferencescreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<preference android:key="sample" 
  android:summary="can open other activity" 
  android:title="click here">
</preference>

<edittextpreference android:key="Name" 
  android:summary="Add user Name." 
  android:title="Your Name">
</edittextpreference>

</preferencescreen>
```

Then I have created a new java class called Preferences in /src/main/java/package/ with following content;

```
package com.domain.mobile.tipcalculator.app;

import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceFragment {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
  }
}
```

Then to my understanding this is all I need. I m not getting any errors on compilation time but when I click on the 3 dots on top right and click on "Settings" I still don't see the page come up. Any ideas? Thank you.

P.S. I am using PreferenceFragment because my min sdk requirement is 11.

Answer (score 7):

To use menus like that, you have to create a menu xml file then inflate it and then switch between the menu item ids so that you can handle click events like the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.preferences:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PreferenceActivity.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

You should be able to achieve what you need this way and I hope this helped.

Comment: I was using wrong method, I should have looked into "Menu" rather than "Preferences". Thank you very much. Looking into xml changes and will attempt again. Thanks.